# SPF- and DKIM- align fails on a few emails from a larger batch

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

We are sending large numbers of emails (hundreds of thousands) mostly for our clients. Of course, we have configures SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records properly for all domains who use us. We pass all tests on various SPF and DKIM validators, and vast majority of emails is delivered without any trouble.

The problem is that almost in every delivery, there are a couple of emails where we get DMARC failure report without apparent reason.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feedback>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <report_metadata>
  <org_name>blabla.com</org_name>
  <email>info@blabla.com</email>
  <extra_contact_info/>
  <report_id>09b93d$7b9b58f=0f6353445e3e471f@ceps.cz</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1587247202</begin>
      <end>1587333603</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>issue.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>none</p>
    <sp>none</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>123.456.789.101</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>blabla.com</header_from>
      <envelope_from>sender.com</envelope_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>blabla.com</domain>
        <selector>k1</selector>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>sender.com</domain>
        <scope>mfrom</scope>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

This happens just to a very few emails, let's say 1%. Most of the emails pass.
Any experience with it?

Comment: Is it always the same organisation's mail servers sending the DMARC reports, or is it (seemingly) random?

Comment: There are different ones, it looks random.

Comment: See my answer below, it took me a while to spot the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misalignment between SMTP "mailFrom" and the header "From" fields. This quite common if you're using some 3rd party software to send e-mails on your behalf.

See these resources:

- [DMARC failed, but SPF pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/769816/dmarc-failed-but-spf-pass)
- [DMARC/SPF/DKIM not authenticating with third-party mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288490/dmarc-spf-dkim-not-authenticating-with-third-party-mail)
- [How to setup DMARC records if you are outsourcing some, or all, of your email – Part 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tzink/how-to-setup-dmarc-records-if-you-are-outsourcing-some-or-all-of-your-email-part-1)
- [How to setup DMARC records if you are outsourcing some, or all, of your email – Part 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tzink/how-to-setup-your-dmarc-records-if-you-are-outsourcing-some-or-all-of-your-email-part-2)